# Why DispatchQueue.main.async is required when using CoreData, NSFetchedResultsController and Diffable Data Source

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource

When dealing with CoreData, NSFetchedResultsController and Diffable Data Source, I always notice that I need to apply `DispatchQueue.main.async`.

For instance,

### Before applying DispatchQueue.main.async

```
extension ViewController: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
    func controller(_ fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChangeContentWith snapshotReference: NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshotReference) {
        guard let dataSource = self.dataSource else {
            return
        }
        
        var snapshot = snapshotReference as NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<String, NSManagedObjectID>

        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true) { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
        }
    }
}
```

However, after we run `performFetch` in `viewDidLoad`, I will get the following error in `dataSource.apply`

> 'Deadlock detected: calling this method on the main queue with
> outstanding async updates is not permitted and will deadlock. Please
> always submit updates either always on the main queue or always off
> the main queue

I can "resolve" the problem by using the following

### After applying DispatchQueue.main.async

```
extension ViewController: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
    func controller(_ fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChangeContentWith snapshotReference: NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshotReference) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            
            guard let dataSource = self.dataSource else {
                return
            }
            
            var snapshot = snapshotReference as NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<String, NSManagedObjectID>

            dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: true) { [weak self] in
                guard let self = self else { return }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Things work fine after that.

But, we are puzzled on why `DispatchQueue.main.async` is ever required because

1. `performFetch` is run in main thread.
2. Callback `didChangeContentWith` is run in main thread.
3. `NSFetchedResultsController` is using main CoreData context, not background context.

Hence, we cannot understand why we are getting runtime error if `DispatchQueue.main.async` is not used.

*Do you have idea, why DispatchQueue.main.async is required when using CoreData, NSFetchedResultsController and Diffable Data Source?*

The following are our detailed code snippet.

### CoreDataStack.swift

```
import CoreData

class CoreDataStack {
    public static let INSTANCE = CoreDataStack()
    
    private init() {
    }
    
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "xxx")
        
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // This is a serious fatal error. We will just simply terminate the app, rather than using error_log.
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        
        // So that when backgroundContext write to persistent store, container.viewContext will retrieve update from
        // persistent store.
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        
        // TODO: Not sure these are required...
        //
        //container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
        //container.viewContext.undoManager = nil
        //container.viewContext.shouldDeleteInaccessibleFaults = true
        
        return container
    }()
    
    lazy var backgroundContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        let backgroundContext = persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()

        // TODO: Not sure these are required...
        //
        backgroundContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
        //backgroundContext.undoManager = nil
        
        return backgroundContext
    }()
    
    // https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/nsbatchdeleterequest-core-data/
    func mergeChanges(_ changes: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
        
        // TODO:
        //
        // (1) Should this method called from persistentContainer.viewContext, or backgroundContext?
        // (2) Should we include backgroundContext in the into: array?
        
        NSManagedObjectContext.mergeChanges(
            fromRemoteContextSave: changes,
            into: [persistentContainer.viewContext, backgroundContext]
        )
    }
}
```

### NoteViewController.swift

```
class NoteViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ...
        initDataSource()
        initNSTabInfoProvider()
    }

    
    private func initNSTabInfoProvider() {
        self.nsTabInfoProvider = NSTabInfoProvider(self)
        
        // Trigger performFetch
        _ = self.nsTabInfoProvider.fetchedResultsController
    }

    private func initDataSource() {
        let dataSource = DataSource(
            collectionView: tabCollectionView,
            cellProvider: { [weak self] (collectionView, indexPath, objectID) -> UICollectionViewCell? in
                
                guard let self = self else { return nil }
                
                ...
            }
        )
        
        self.dataSource = dataSource
    }
```

### NSTabInfoProvider.swift

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

// We are using https://github.com/yccheok/earthquakes-WWDC20 as gold reference.
class NSTabInfoProvider {
    
    weak var fetchedResultsControllerDelegate: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate?
    
    lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSTabInfo> = {
        
        let fetchRequest = NSTabInfo.fetchSortedRequest()
        
        // Create a fetched results controller and set its fetch request, context, and delegate.
        let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(
            fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
            managedObjectContext: CoreDataStack.INSTANCE.persistentContainer.viewContext,
            sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
            cacheName: nil
        )
        
        controller.delegate = fetchedResultsControllerDelegate
        
        // Perform the fetch.
        do {
            try controller.performFetch()
        } catch {
            error_log(error)
        }
        
        return controller
    }()
    
    var nsTabInfos: [NSTabInfo]? {
        return fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects
    }
    
    init(_ fetchedResultsControllerDelegate: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate) {
        self.fetchedResultsControllerDelegate = fetchedResultsControllerDelegate
    }
    
    func getNSTabInfo(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSTabInfo? {
        guard let sections = self.fetchedResultsController.sections else { return nil }
        return sections[indexPath.section].objects?[indexPath.item] as? NSTabInfo
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out the root cause of the problem.

This is due to my insufficient understanding on the lazy initialised variable.

### Problematic code

```
class NSTabInfoProvider {
    lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSTabInfo> = {
        
        let fetchRequest = NSTabInfo.fetchSortedRequest()
        
        // Create a fetched results controller and set its fetch request, context, and delegate.
        let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(
            fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
            managedObjectContext: CoreDataStack.INSTANCE.persistentContainer.viewContext,
            sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
            cacheName: nil
        )
        
        controller.delegate = fetchedResultsControllerDelegate
        
        // Perform the fetch.
        do {
            try controller.performFetch()
        } catch {
            error_log(error)
        }
        
        return controller
    }()
}

self.nsTabInfoProvider = NSTabInfoProvider(self)
// Trigger performFetch
_ = self.nsTabInfoProvider.fetchedResultsController
```

1. It is wrong to trigger `performFetch` in lazy variable initialisation.
2. Because that will trigger callback.
3. Callback might try to access `NSTabInfoProvider`'s `fetchedResultsController`.
4. But `NSTabInfoProvider`'s `fetchedResultsController` is **NOT** fully initialised, as the code is not yet return from the lazy variable initialisation scope.

---

### Fixed code

The solution would be

```
class NSTabInfoProvider {
    lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSTabInfo> = {
        
        let fetchRequest = NSTabInfo.fetchSortedRequest()
        
        // Create a fetched results controller and set its fetch request, context, and delegate.
        let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(
            fetchRequest: fetchRequest,
            managedObjectContext: CoreDataStack.INSTANCE.persistentContainer.viewContext,
            sectionNameKeyPath: nil,
            cacheName: nil
        )
        
        controller.delegate = fetchedResultsControllerDelegate
        
        return controller
    }()

    func performFetch() {
        do {
            try self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch {
            error_log(error)
        }
    }
}

self.nsTabInfoProvider = NSTabInfoProvider(self)
self.nsTabInfoProvider.performFetch()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is to do with the fact the models are probably added or updated using a background context

```
lazy var backgroundContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let backgroundContext = persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()

    // TODO: Not sure these are required...
    //
    backgroundContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
    //backgroundContext.undoManager = nil
    
    return backgroundContext
}()
```

This could be why you need to push everything to the main thread because in your method you are trying to update your datasource (by extension your tableview) which is a UI component, thus it needs to be on the main thread.

You can think of the main thread as a UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

Please note the highlighted part of the run time error.

> 'Deadlock detected: calling this method on the main queue with outstanding async updates is not permitted and will deadlock. **Please always submit updates either always on the main queue or always off the main queue**

This is clearly mentioned in the [UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource.apply](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource/3375795-apply) docs as well.

> #### Discussion
>
> The diffable data source computes the difference between the collection view’s current state and the new state in the applied snapshot, which is an O(n) operation, where n is the number of items in the snapshot.
>
> **You can safely call this method from a background queue, but you must do so consistently in your app. Always call this method exclusively from the main queue or from a background queue.**

#### What do you need to do?

Check for all call sites of `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource.apply` in your code and make sure those are consistently off / on main thread. You can't call this from multiple threads (one time from main, other time from some other thread etc.)